# Проблема при добавлении в конец double linked list, C++

Tags: c++, ооп, linked-list

Есть два класса: первый - Game, второй - List (он же double listed list).

```
 class Game {
        int direction;
        int points;
        int allMoney;
        Game * nextPtr;
        Game * prevPtr;
    public:
        friend class List<Game>;
        Game(int _points, int _direction)
        {
            points = _points;
            direction = _direction;
            allMoney = 0;
        }
    };

    template <class NodeType>
    class List
    {
    public:
        List();
        void insertAtBack(NodeType&);
        int isEmpty() const { return firstPtr == 0; }
    private:
        int Size;
        NodeType * firstPtr;
        NodeType * lastPtr;
    };

    template<class NodeType>
    List<NodeType>::List()
    {
        firstPtr = lastPtr = 0;
        Size = 0;
    }

    template<class NodeType>
    void List<NodeType>::insertAtBack(NodeType& value)
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            firstPtr = lastPtr = &value;
        else
        {
            value.prevPtr = lastPtr;
            lastPtr->nextPtr = &value;
            lastPtr = &value;
        }
        Size++;
    }
```

Также есть main:

```
void main()
{
    int pointsArr[12] = { 50, -100, 200, -150, 250, -50, 100, -200, 150, -50, 150, 100 };
    int directionArr[12] = { 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1 };

    List<Game> quest;

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        Game option(pointsArr[i], directionArr[i]);
        quest.insertAtBack(option);
    }
}
```

Нужно создать double linked list из объектов типа Game. Проблема состоит в том, то при первой итерации в цикле main начальные значения класса List инициализируются правильно, но при второй и последующих итерациях начальные значения объекта

```
quest
```

затираются новыми значениями объекта

```
option
```

Соответственно, в linked list не добавляется второй, третий и тд. элементы, а постоянно обновляются начальные firstPtr и lastPtr. Как быть?

Comment: Ну правильно, объект `option` после каждой итерации выходит из области видимости, делая все указатели и ссылки на него невалидными. Используйте `std::vector`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Так как аргумент временный объект, на адрес этот не стоит надеятся, что будет валидным. Нужно создавать новый экземпляр в куче. И не забыть освобождать память с помощью `delete`.

```
template<class NodeType>
    void List<NodeType>::insertAtBackMove(NodeType& value)
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            firstPtr = lastPtr =  new NodeType ( value ) ;
        else
        {
            value.prevPtr = lastPtr;
            value.nextPtr = nullptr ;
            lastPtr->nextPtr =  new NodeType ( value );
            lastPtr = lastPtr->nextPtr;
        }
        Size++;
    }
```

или в версии 11 :

```
template<class NodeType>
        void List<NodeType>::insertAtBack(NodeType && value)
        {
            if (isEmpty())
                firstPtr = lastPtr =  new NodeType ( std::move(value) ) ;
            else
            {
                value.prevPtr = lastPtr;
                value.nextPtr = nullptr ;
                lastPtr->nextPtr =  new NodeType ( std::move(value) );
                lastPtr = lastPtr->nextPtr;
            }
            Size++;
        }
  ...
  quest.insertAtBack(std::move(option));
```